# PHP - Forma más abreviada de imprimir una cosa u otra dependiendo de una variable

Tags: php

Me gustaría saber **la forma más abreviada de imprimir una cosa u otra dependiendo de una condición** con PHP. En mi caso sería imprimir `'true'` o `'false'` según si una variable es verdadera o no:

**codigo.php**

```
<?php
    $variable = true;
?>
```

**index.php**

```
var variable_js = <?= $variable ?>; // Esto imprime '1' o '' dependiendo de si es true o false
```

Como sabrán, por defecto PHP imprime un `'1'` o una cadena en blanco `''`, lo que quiero es imprimir `'true'` o `'false'` **sin hacer todo esto** (*No es mucho código pero recuerdo haber encontrado una forma muy simple de hacerlo y si se puede hacer mejor, porqué no*):

```
var variable_js = <?php if ($variable) echo 'true'; else echo 'false' ?>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza un operador ternario

```
var variable_js = <?= $variable ? 'true' : 'false' ?>;
```

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que necesitaba. Aceptaré la pregunta cuando me dejen. Gracias